# Is the pz orbital wave function three- or four-dimensional?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals

The wave function of the $2\mathrm{p}_z$ orbital is

$$Ψ = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2π}}\left(\frac Z a\right)^{5/2} r \mathrm e^{-Zr/a}\cos θ.$$

I'm confused if this function will be a three-dimensional function or a four-dimensional function?

My professor told me that

$$z/r = \cos θ,$$

where $θ$ is the angle made by $r$ with the $z$ axis. So, I guess it will be four-dimensional since we would have to then plug in

$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$

in the equation.

But when he plotted the function, he plotted a three-dimensional one! What is the correct answer and why?

Comment: The wave function is a function of $x, y$ and $z$. That is all. Why would you create a fourth dimension ?

Comment: The expression is in spherical coordinates, the coordinates as (r,theta,phi) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system .

Comment: If you plug in particular values of x,y,z and get a value of the function,which axis will you ploit it on?

Comment: You have to start with a simpler question: is $\sin x$ a one-dimensional or two-dimensional function?

Comment: two dimensional

Comment: I think we have found the misconception. Typically, when we refer to the dimension of a function, we are describing how many input variables it depends upon. In the case of $\sin(x)$, this is just 1. To plot the value of the function, we need one additional dimension, but that's not the same as saying $\sin(x)$ is two dimensional. $\sin(x)$ has a value for every point in one dimensional space. The pz orbital has a value for every point in 3 dimensional space.

Comment: A three dimensional function(assuming the domain is $R^{2}$ )will have a value for every point in 2 dimensional space. Similarly,a 4 dimensional function will have a value for every point in 3 dimensional space.So,shouldn't the orbital function be a 4 dimensional one?

Comment: That's not the way we use these words. A function has 3 variables, hence it is 3-dimensional. A _graph_ of it is 4D, but that's another story.

Comment: Rather than debate semantics- the short answer you are looking for is that this function only needs two input values to be determined: r and theta. That is because the value of the function for each (r, theta) pair is constant with respect to the third variable phi in the spherical coordinate system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wavefunction covers 3-dimensional space. Formally, it maps each point in space to a complex number. That is, it is a function that takes a point in 3-dimensional space as input and returns a complex number as output: $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

There are many ways to represent 3-dimensional space: cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$, spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$, cylindrical coordinates $(z, r, \theta)$, to name the most common. We have these different ways because functions might look "nice" in one coordinate system and not nice in another.

As it turns out, the wave function for the $p_{z}$ orbital looks "nice" in spherical coordinates, that is, $\Psi(r, \theta, \phi)$. It looks less nice in cartesian coordinates, but you can do the replacement for $\theta$ and $\phi$ as noted in the question. However, people do not usually mix coordinates systems together because they are redundant. For example, no one writes $r\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$. They write either $r^{2}$ or $x^{2}+y^{2}$.

To conclude, the $p_{z}$ orbital you have written is a function of 3 variables: $r, \theta, \phi$. It just happens not to depend on $\phi$, so it looks like just a function of $r$ and $\theta$. Forget this concept of dimensionality because it's not doing you any favors.

Comment: you have written $r$ as the square root of $x^2+y^2$. Shouldn't it be the square root of $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Comment: Only in spherical coordinates. In cylindrical coordinates, it's just a function of x and y. Honestly, though, the point is don't mix coordinates. If you're hung up on what the definition of r is, then you've missed the point.